# Remove option from union after user select any option from it

Tags: typescript

Maybe title does not describe my problem properly but what I want is this, in my React component there is a prop with all possible options  defined in this union:

```
type ControlledLayerTypes = 'overlay' | 'baselayer' | 'clusterlayer';
Component ... {
  someProp: ControlledLayerTypes[];
}
```

When user provide one of these options that option should be excluded so user can't enter same value multiple times.

```
<Component someProp={['overlay' ... do no allow `overlay` again here, only allow 'baselayer' and 'clusterlayer' once]}/>
```

Comment: Are there really only three choices?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea length is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a permutation of all allowed tuples:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'
type ControlledLayerTypes = 'overlay' | 'baselayer' | 'clusterlayer';

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];


type Props = {
  someProps: TupleUnion<ControlledLayerTypes>
}

const Button: FC<Props> = () => <button></button>

const jsx = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'baselayer', 'clusterlayer']} /> // ok

const jsx2 = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'baselayer', 'clusterlayer', 'overlay',]} /> // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFAwCeYSchEAdjFQA2gpABMAMijZIoAFQ5IAznAC8dCADcZgqbTgAfOgCMUipDulQ9h2mkEBXRTG1SZtANzNWCuLPtgRAFVeYD4AHkC4JAAPZ15RZScoYF4Ac2wEKNikeOUUXjYAbQBdVTgSgD4ynGY4coBlOBS4QOKALjgAUWi7e1EkCOx6qpi4hLheJC0oOAB%20coA6JYQh0o6-AKRg0N4w7t7%20wbhh7EKlhZXj4orPEkLWzy92TjgABSowZTUausVqJHeEE%20638QRC4R4-CEIgkrjkCkUFWYJC8aD4TjgACF7DAYHwOkQwoDPlU1AAKACUqiqYSMOLxvAqYQA9HTcXwkcw0bwMQArRTRMphbHs3hwP4gAEfRQqHCFWiaFxsWjYWgmMwWNyq3pOJVuYpkZlVZnMuAQADWqPR8H50QATEKRQzxf9iTK5QrphYVcZTOY4T7bA5dVBNVZVYrQ7pMAa4Ea46aYpwMGIolAqFAgA)

If you want to make every element optional, use this util:

```js
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S?] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S?]>;
}[U];
```

I have added `S?`

Example with optional elements

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'
type ControlledLayerTypes = 'overlay' | 'baselayer' | 'clusterlayer';

type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends (string | undefined)[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S?] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S?]>;
}[U];


type Props = {
  someProps: TupleUnion<ControlledLayerTypes>
}

const Button: FC<Props> = () => <button></button>

const jsx = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'baselayer', 'clusterlayer']} /> // ok
const jsx2 = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'baselayer']} /> // ok


const jsx3 = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'baselayer', 'clusterlayer', 'overlay',]} /> // expected error
const jsx4 = <Button someProps={['overlay', 'overlay',]} /> // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFAwCeYSchEAdjFQA2gpABMAMijZIoAFQ5IAznAC8dCADcZgqbTgAfOgCMUipDulQ9h2mkEBXRTG1SZtANzNWCuLPtgRAFVeYD4AHkC4JAAPZ15RZScoYF4Ac2wEKNikeOUUXjYAbQBdVTgSgD4ynGY4coBlOBS4QOKALjgAUWi7e1EkCOx6qpi4hLheJC0oOAB%20coA6JYQh2dKOvwCkYNDeMO7e-sG4YexCpYWVk7WKzxJC1s8vdk44AAUqMGU1GrrFaiQHwgXw2-iCIXCPH4QhEElccgUigqzBIXjQfCccAAQvYYDA%20B0iGEgV8qmoABQASlUVTCRlx%20N4FTCAHp6Xi%20MjmOjeJiAFaKaJlMI4jm8OD-ECAz6KFQ4Qq0TQuNi0bC0ExmCxuNW9JzKtzFMgsqosllwCAAa25GPgAuiACZhaLGRKASTZfLFdMLKrjKZzPDaIa4MaQ2bLV5rbzbYKAMxOhl8V1S91yhVKqA%20tUagOWX22Bx6zOBtUZrPB0OmrKcDBiKJQKhQKP8wUAFgTYuT0uBHvT3t0pf7KswFZNZpiNeconrjaAA)

Comment: Pls keep in mind, if you have a long union you can boil a water on your CPU

Comment: Its okish solution, but it still offers me all options and I must provide all 3 options, can I add Partial to it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, try to wrap it in Partial. If Partial not work try add `?` right after `S` in above util.

Comment: It works good, only problem is that it offers me all options when adding new item. But you helped me with example and link. I will try to polish it to get what I want. Thanks.

Comment: adding partial over TupleUnion<ControlledLayerTypes> gives me this type `element: "overlay" | "baselayer" | "clusterlayer" | undefined`, can I somehow get `element: ("overlay" | undefined ) |  ("baselayer" | unefined) | ("clusterlayer" | undefined`) ?

Comment: I tried that before and that gives me this error: `Type '[...R, (S | undefined)?]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string[]'`

Comment: @Nenad made another one update. It should work

Comment: Difference is I am using `R extends string[] = []` instead of any, can I do it without any?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237007/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-nenad).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to do this is to define the type of `someProp` as a union of all the possible configurations as tuples. With just three options, that's viable — there are only a few possibilities (it would be nine, but with no duplicates it's only six). It gets progressively less and less workable the more possibilities there are:

```typescript
type ControlledLayerTypesArray =
      ["overlay", "baselayer", "clusterlayer"]
    | ["overlay", "clusterlayer", "baselayer"]
    | ["baselayer", "overlay", "clusterlayer"]
    | ["baselayer", "clusterlayer", "overlay"]
    | ["clusterlayer", "overlay", "baselayer"]
    | ["clusterlayer", "baselayer", "overlay"]
;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGEIA7GHAG3aQBMAZFakigAVWkgDOAQShQBcALzk4ylQG18EAG5D2A-ABoCAIxTikuwVAME07AK7iYOgUPwBdJSoA+cdVufU1vi2Dk5QFq6G+CZmEVYeKnA+6jHmLlZR-uF6USGOAa4J3r7RpmmWQXlhcUFZFu6eysnB9vnZFZna7UGpNUVNJVUFGcZlNZ0BDRTkaCyOcACiAB4o4FwKcAAUYDhg4gBccADe4rhIAAq7h0ysHFx86aJ0UjICAL4AlAoAfMeNcEQYHYoMw4AAebjATQAem+FDe01mzHmAHMIBBuMtVmB1vJwVi1vRTiALrt5Ec-F16rlWtV0j0xvS3G84LDEXN4EIcFACTj6Hiwbz1sTSRAwOTKZMor16RNuszWXDyEA)

This is the plodders like me do it. People who really "get" TypeScript do it the way [captain-yossarian shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69143833/157247).

Comment: also nice solution, thanks, but it would be very long to include when I want to provide only 1 or 2 options, this solution is valid for fixed 3 options :)

Comment: @Nenad - Exactly. As I said, it gets progressively less and less workable the more there are. For your three I'd probably do the above. Even just going to four I'd hope I could find something like captain-yossarian's answer (because my current level of TypeScript isn't up to *writing* that answer :-D ).